# Migration issues of GraalVM Native Images to AWS Graviton2(Arm64) Processors

Tags: maven, aws-lambda, github-actions, graalvm-native-image

Existing Implementation:

- All Lambdas configured for x86_64 Architecture.
- These lambdas are to run a GraalVM compiled **Native image** to execute some functionality.
- The compilation of this native image is done with Maven using native-maven-plugin(0.9.9) & the command: **mvn -B -DskipTests -Pnative clean package**
- We are using this as part of Github actions in our build step.

To move the Lambdas to Graviton2 instances:-

- We changed the architecture to 'arm64' in the template according to this [article](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-aws-lambda-functions-to-arm-based-aws-graviton2-processors/). This results in this error: `'./native-executable: cannot execute binary file'`
- To get it to work on arm64 based processor, we have tried to recompile this java code for aarm64 .
  Here are few of the things I did:-

  1. Change graalvm setup on Github to arm64 base by using [DeLaGuardo/setup-graalvm](https://github.com/DeLaGuardo/setup-graalvm) and then getting the following error: `cannot execute binary file: Exec format error Error: Process completed with exit code 126.`
  2. Tried Graalvm package install & install native image, getting java11-aarch64/x64/bin/gu: cannot execute `binary file: Exec format error`.
  3. Tried [run-on-arch package](https://github.com/uraimo/run-on-arch-action) but it gives me an error of `'Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?'`
  4. Also getting `'mvn command not found'` when I try to create a build without Graalvm.

So to summarise, a simple architecture value change of 'arm64' is not sufficient to run native images on Graviton2 based AWS Lambdas & lot of migration related issues on Github - Java - Arm64 stack.

It would be greatly appreciated if someone could help me to move forward from this bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

GraalVM does support arm64 https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/reference-manual/native-image/ARM64/ as of version 21.0.

1. For github actions just changing "amd64" to "arm64" wouldn't work, you need to use qemu emulator as well
2. It's not clear how you got github action setup but you can take some references from here https://docs.docker.com/ci-cd/github-actions/
3. From the error it looks `mvn` is not installed

There are some steps here as well for aarch64 https://www.graalvm.org/22.0/docs/getting-started/linux-aarch64/

Answer (score 0):

From the errors you've posted, it looks like the docker process might not have enough resources to compile the native executable.

I would double-check your GitHub actions config and add more memory if possible.

If you are using the AWS runtime interface client as part of your solution you will need version 2.1.1. This is the first version to support aarch64.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-lambda-java-runtime-interface-client</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```